# How does Kong Api Gateway http-log works

Tags: linux, kong

As per Kong documentation

**

```
$ curl -X POST http://kong:8001/apis/{api}/plugins \
    --data "name=http-log" \
    --data "config.http_endpoint=http://mockbin.org/bin/:id/" \
    --data "config.method=POST" \
    --data "config.timeout=1000" \
    --data "config.keepalive=1000"
```

**

log will be create at http_endpoint.
I am unable to understand how does kong http-log works.
Suppose my request host is x.x.x.x and kong in installed in my local system,where should i look for log generated after adding http-log plugin.is http-log is accessible using console?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a listener on the location which is specified as config.http_endpoint. Endpoint has to handle config.method. It will receive a big JSON with all the log info in it.

Check example log JSON at [click here](https://getkong.org/plugins/http-log/)

My Suggestion:

Best option here is to set this end point to the elastic search end point to receive all your logs and use Kibana UI on top of elastic to add the visualization to your log data.

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP Log -
>   Send request and response logs to an HTTP server.

the config.http_endpoint is your log server where you can view your logs